1D FFT along different dimensions of 3D array in MATLAB vs C++
This maybe a simple question, but unfortunately I am unable to find a simple answer to. I am taking 1D FFT of a 3D matrix (tensor) of size: # of rows by # of columns by # of matrices and so in MATLAB this translates to:
clearvars; clc; close all;
Nx = 8;  
Ny = 4; 
Nz= 6;
Lx =16;
Ly = 6;
dx = Lx/Nx; 
dy = Ly/Ny;
%-----------
xi_x =  (2*pi)/Lx;
yi_y =  (2*pi)/Ly;
xi  = ((0:Nx-1)/Nx)*(2*pi);
yi  = ((0:Ny-1)/Ny)*(2*pi);
x =  xi/xi_x;
y =  yi/yi_y;
zlow = 0; %a
zupp =6; %b
Lz = (zupp-zlow);
zgl = cos ( pi * ( 0 : Nz ) / Nz )';
zgl = (1/2)*(((zupp-zlow)*zgl) + (zupp+zlow));
[X,Z,Y] = meshgrid(x,zgl,y); %this gives 3d grid with z-by-x-by-y size (i.e. ZXY)
%ICs
A = 2*pi / Lx;
B = 2*pi / Ly;
u = (Z-zlow) .* (Z-zupp) .* sin(A*X).* sin(B*Y);
uh1 =(fft(u,[],1));
uh2 =(fft(u,[],2));
uh3 =(fft(u,[],3));

This produces a 3D tensor with (Nz+1) rows and Nx columns and Ny matrices and taking the 1D FFT along each "column" of u is represented by uh1 =(fft(u,[],1)); and the 1D FFT along each "row" of us is represented by uh2 =(fft(u,[],2)); according to the MATLAB FFT documentation.
This works fine with me when using FFT and Eigen library in C++! However, I am not sure what
uh3 =(fft(u,[],3));

means? what is the 3rd dimension represents? I thought that meant how many matrices I had inside of the tensor u? I am unsure how to calculate this in my C++ code.
Example of C++ code:
static const int nx = 8; 
static const int ny = 4;
static const int nz = 6;

int main(){
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> uFun((nz+1),nx,ny);//tensor(row,col,matrix)
uFun.setZero();
for(int x = 0; x< nx; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y< ny; y++){
                for(int z = 0; z< nz+1; z++){
                uFun(z,x,y) = //define function u same as MATLAB
            }
        }
    }
//define matrix and copy the tensor into it
//map tensor to matrix

Eigen::MatrixXd dummy((nz+1),nx); //to match tensor slices
dummy.setZero();
Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> Tensor2D((nz+1),nx);   //tensor(row,col,matrix)
Tensor2D.setZero();

Tensor2D = uFun.slice(std::array{0, 0, 3}, std::array{nz + 1, nx, 1}).reshape(std::array{nz + 1, nx}) ;
dummy = static_cast<MatrixType<double>>(Eigen::Map<const MatrixType<double>>(Tensor2D.data(), (nz+1), nx));
Eigen::MatrixXcd tempOut1((nz+1),nx);
//uh1= fft(u,[],1);
    for (int k=0; k< dummy.cols(); k++){
        tempOut1.col(k) = fft.fwd(dummy.col(k));        
    }
//uh2= fft(u,[],2);
Eigen::MatrixXcd tempOut((nz+1),nx);
Eigen::VectorXcd row(nx);
    for (int k=0; k< (dummy.rows()); k++){
        fft.fwd(row, dummy.row(k));
        tempOut.row(k) = row;
    }

}


The above code works for uh1=fft(u,[],1) and uh2=fft(u,[],2) but not uh3=fft(u,[],3) which I am not sure what does it represent here?
Here's the MATLAB FFT documentation that I am following with:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-5
NOTE: I know I can use FFTW library for easier use with Eigen tensors, but in the meantime this has been much more user-friendly to me "personally"
EDIT:
Thanks to @CrisLuengo I have better idea of what each dimension represents here. What I am trying to do looks like the following in MATLAB:
numRows=Nz+1;numCols=Nx;
for i= 1:numRows
   for j= 1:numCols
      uk(i,j,:) = fft(u(i,j,:));
   end
end

where the above code is basically uh3 =(fft(u,[],3)); and now using EigenFFT maybe something like this (NOT TESTED yet):
for (int i = 0; i < dummy.rows(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dummy.cols(); ++j) {
            int index =  i * dummy.cols() + j; // Flattened index
            VectorXcd slice = dummy.row(index);
            tempOut.row(index) = fft.fwd(slice);
        }
    }



who wrote the matlab code?

I’m not sure what the question is. You seem confused about the FFT when it is computed along the 3rd dimension,  but not when it is computed along the first or second one. Is that right?

@CrisLuengo Yes, basically!

The FFT is just a computation. If you can do it along dimension 1, then you can do it along dimension 3. What it means when you do it along dimension 3 depends on what dimension 3 means. Say you have a time series of images, you stack them along the 3rd dimension of a 3D array. So dimension 3 is time. The FFT along the 3rd dimension then is just the FFT of a time signal recorded by a pixel sensor in the camera. You get one FFT per pixel. Does that make sense? I've worked with images where the 3rd dimension is depth, wavelength, time, and probably some other things too.

If you have a 3D array composed by stacking unrelated 2D images, then the 3rd dimension has no meaning, and doing any computation along it is meaningless.  Maybe you're working with data that is not related to imaging, the examples above hopefully still clarify things, as the same logic applies to any other field of computation.

@CrisLuengo Yes this makes sense!

@CrisLuengo I think I understand what to do but my C/C++ syntax might be off. I will edit my post.

This should work:
for (int i = 0; i < dummy.rows(); ++i){
        VectorXd slice = dummy.row(i);
        VectorXcd tmpOut(nx);
        fft.fwd(tmpOut, slice);
        for (int j = 0; j < dummy.cols(); ++j){
            tempOut(i, j) = tmpOut(j);
        }
    }

    std::cout<<tempOut<<endl;



this returns the same result as looping over all rows only
